# Exception while checking for an image on a website using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to Selenium. I was trying to check if the header logo if a website is displayed or not. I have written the code after searching the internet regarding how to check if the image is displayed or not. If I use the function isDisplayed(), the code works fine, but I tried it using the JavascriptExecutor, and I am getting an exception which I don't understand.

Here is the code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Header_logo {

public WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Header_logo obj1=new Header_logo();
    obj1.launch_test();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void launch_test() 
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://northeastindiaholidays.com";
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    WebElement image1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div/h1/a/img"));

    Boolean imageLoaded1 = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", image1);
    if (!imageLoaded1)
    {
         System.out.println("1. Image is not present");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("1. Got it");
    }

    WebElement image2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div/div[3]"));

    Boolean imageLoaded2 = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", image2);
    if (!imageLoaded2)
    {
         System.out.println("2. Image is not present");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("2. Got it");
    }

    driver.close();
}
```

}

I am getting this exception every time I run this code

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: syntax error
Command duration or timeout: 38 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'Zac-PC', ip: '192.168.73.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',      os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Session ID: b727b844-9798-4d26-9362-23273d87abc9
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=29.0.1}]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
at Link_test.main(Link_test.java:39)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: syntax error
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'Zac-PC', ip: '192.168.73.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at <anonymous class>.handleEvaluateEvent(http://northeastindiaholidays.com/:67)
```

The page link opens fine, but the check doesn't seem to be working though. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code. Also always use **implicit wait** while finding the elements. For images it is advised to use **cssSelector** whenever it is available.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Header_logo {

public WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;

public static void main(String[] args) {

TestDriver obj1=new TestDriver();
obj1.launch_test();
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void launch_test() 
{
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
baseUrl = "http://northeastindiaholidays.com";
driver.get(baseUrl);

WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='North East India Holidays']"));
//use this if you have alt attribute in that image element 
String imgName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='North East India Holidays']")).getAttribute("alt");

Boolean loaded = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete && " + "typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && " + "arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", image);
if (loaded){
     System.out.println(imgName + " Image is present and status is : " + loaded);
}
else
{
    System.out.println(imgName + "Image is NOT present and status is : " + loaded);
}

driver.close();
}}
```

Similarly do it for other images

Comment: Thank you so much Bharath. I have two question though- 
1.If the image doesn't has an alt tag, what should I do?
2.Why is it advised to use the CSS selector for images, rather than the xpath?

Comment: 1. You can use other attributes properties like **'src'** value or if no other option then you can go for xpath.                      2. Css describes the look and formatting of elements (which suites best for images in your case)Also identifying elements through CSS selectors is fast compare to xpaths. You can use xpath too but use relative xpaths (the one which you used is absolute). Example relative xpath in your case is :    By.xpath("//h1[@class='logo']/a/img")